# How do I add a service stack license to a .NET core project?

Tags: servicestack

For my service stack license I am used to adding a web config entry

`<add key="servicestack:license" ... />`

How do I achieve a similar effect in ServiceStack.Core since there is no web config?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The license key can be registered using any of the options listed at: https://servicestack.net/download#register

So while there's no `Web.config` you can use any of the other 3 options like registering the `SERVICESTACK_LICENSE` Environment Variable.

Also whilst .NET Core doesn't need to use `Web.config` or `App.config` you can still use one in .NET Core in ServiceStack for storing any `<appSettings>`, e.g:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="servicestack:license" value="{LicenseKey}" />
    </appSettings>    
</configuration>
```

But you'll need to register the license key explicitly from the AppSettings with:

```
using ServiceStack;

public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() 
        : base("Service Name", typeof(MyServices).GetAssembly()) 
    {
        var licenseKeyText = AppSettings.GetString("servicestack:license");
        Licensing.RegisterLicense(licenseKeyText);
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to use `Web.config` you can use any other [AppSettings options](http://docs.servicestack.net/appsettings).

Comment: You are the golden example of customer service. Thanks Mythz, much appreciated.